# Random select rows from CSV and repeat by X number of times

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

Im new to Python and created a script that picks out random rows from a csv with two columns. But it only picks out one random row from each column once.  This is my code:

```
import csv
import random

with open('Sheettwo.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    chosen_row = random.choice(list(csv_reader))

    paraone = (chosen_row[1])
    paratwo = (chosen_row[2])

    print(f'{paraone}\n{paratwo}\n')
```

I need to repeat this X number of times so (for example) 4 values are randomly selected (two from each column). How do i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to do it is to first store your data in a list, and then pick values from it.

```
import csv
import random

with open('Sheettwo.csv', 'r') as csv_file:

    lines = [tuple(line) for line in csv.reader(csv_file)]


n = 4 #  number of row you want to pick elements from

chosen_rows = random.choices(lines, k=n) 
 # pick n rows in the list

chosen_values = [random.choice(row) for row in chosen_rows]
  # pick a value from each row

print('\n'.join(chosen_values))
```

I hope it will be useful...

Comment: Thanks thats worked great. But it outputs the values into single lines e.g:

choice 6 choice 25
choice 13 choice 32
choice 3 choice 22
choice 4 choice 23

Is there a way to output it separately and group in pairs of two?

Comment: Thanks rambi. Perfect. It outputs 'Chosen row X:' But how do i get it to output a random value for each group from a list e.g names = ['Name 1', 'Name 2','Name 3','Name 4'] ? I appreciate your help.

Comment: I want to be sure to undestand what you want : if your data is [(1,2),(3, 4),(5,6),(7,8),(9,10),(11,12)], does the output 1 6 3 10 suit you ? You want to pick a random value of a row for 4 random row in your file ?     And is it still good if I just pick 4 elements at random in the file , like 1 2 9 10 : can I pick 2 values in the same row ?

Comment: Yes i want to pick a random value for the 4 rows. I need to specify the random values though. The same value cannot be picked twice. I added this to the end of your code and it kind of worked but didnt escape correctly - print(random.choice(names),'\n','\n'.join(c),'\n')

Answer (score 2):

- You need to keep your `list(csv_reader)` around because `csv.reader` is a lazy iterator so after it's gone through the entire thing once... it's done
- If repetitions are fine, just call `random.choice` in a loop
- Otherwise use `random.choices(lines, k=n)` where k is the number of rows you want to select